# I can't delete azure alert

Tags: azure, alert, azure-powershell

i have the following alert in Azure:

```
PS C:\> Get-AzResource -Name "alert for rg"

Name              : alert for rg ResourceGroupName : plaz-rg2 ResourceType      : Microsoft.AlertsManagement/actionRules Location    : global ResourceId        : /subscriptions/XXXX/resourceGroups/plaz-rg2/providers/Microsoft.Alerts
                    Management/actionRules/alert for rg
```

I was deleting it before but it is still visible.

I can't delete resource group because of it.

```
PS C:\> Remove-AzResourceGroup -name "plaz-rg2"

Confirm
Are you sure you want to remove resource group 'plaz-rg2'
[Y] Yes  [N] No  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"): Y
Remove-AzResourceGroup : Long running operation failed with status 'Conflict'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Remove-AzResourceGroup -name "plaz-rg2"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Remove-AzResourceGroup], CloudException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Resources.RemoveAzureResourceGroupCmdlet
```

When I'm trying to delete the alert alone it is not possible

```
PS C:\> Remove-AzResource -Name "alert for rg" -ResourceType Microsoft.AlertsManagement/actionRules

Confirm
Are you sure you want to delete the following resource:
/subscriptions/XXXX/providers/Microsoft.AlertsManagement/actionRules/alert%20for%20rg
[Y] Yes  [N] No  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"): y
Remove-AzResource : ResourceNotFound : The Resource 'Microsoft.AlertsManagement/actionRules/alert for rg' under resource gr
oup '<null>' was not found.
At line:1 char:1
+ Remove-AzResource -Name "alert for rg" -ResourceType Microsoft.Alerts ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Remove-AzResource], ErrorResponseMessageException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.RemoveAzureResourceCmdlet
```

Any idea how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 1):

I see this behavior if we are not passing the ResourceGroupName as input parameter along with Remove-AzResource.

[image: GetAzResource]

[image: RemoveAzResource-Error]

However if you pass in the ResourceGroupName it runs successfully. Please try this out.

[image]

Additional [documentation reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.insights/remove-azurermalertrule?view=azurermps-6.13.0) to remove AlertRule.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have tried. 
PS C:\> Remove-AzResource -Name "alert for rg" -ResourceGroupName "plaz-rg2" -ResourceType "Microsoft.AlertsManagement/actionRules".   It's the same Remove-AzResource : BadRequest : Cannot delete action rule alert for rg as it does not exist. Earlier Get-AzResource is giving back the object details as above.

Comment: Earlier the error was pertaining to "resource group <null> not found" and the one you have above seems to be different. Let me further look into it and see if I can share anything else. Thanks

Comment: @Michel - Can you please confirm if you are able to see the alert rule in Azure Portal ? and able to delete it via portal ?

Comment: Checking Azure Portal : Alerts (classic)>No results to display. I only see this in azure portal when i want to delete the resource group which is containing this alert (this is not visible in the resoure group itself (Home>resource groups) but only in the confirmation blade when i'm deleting the resource group).

Comment: I have updated also Remove-AzResourceGroup -name "plaz-rg2" above as it was wrongly copied before